# Referring to an entire row or column using R1C1 notation

Tags: excel, vba

Referring to an entire row or column using standard notation is straightforward.

e.g. A:A refers to the entire first column. 1:1 refers to the entire first row.

How can I refer to an entire row or column using R1C1 notation in VBA?

Using standard notation I would simply:

```
set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
```

Comment: `R1` for row `$1:$1` and `C1` for `$A:$A`

Comment: R1 refers to cell R1; C1 refers to cell C1. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: yes you need to dictate that the references you are using are `R1C1` and not `A1`

Comment: Thanks - how do I dictate that?

Comment: Well that depends on what you are trying to do.  Not enough info to answer that question.

Comment: I would like to define a range using VBA of a single column using its ordinal position (e.g. column 7).

Comment: Then that is different: `Set rng = ActiveSheet.Columns(1)` or `Set rng = ActiveSheet.Rows(1)`

Comment: AH! So obvious! THANKS! I'll update the question to be more clear if you would kindly elevate your comment to an answer; then I can mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`Columns` and `Rows` can be indexed by number:

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Columns(1)
...
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Rows(1)
```

Answer (score -1):

A:A is equivalent to C1

So if you are doing VBA and run

```
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(C1)"
```

You will get =SUM($A:$A) on the workbook (if you have not set it to R1C1 notation). This works the same for rows, simply exclude the C part of the reference.

Comment: As evident from the [last OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62347205/referring-to-an-entire-row-or-column-using-r1c1-notation#comment110267088_62347205), this is not what they were after. Because Scott Craner never posted [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62347205/referring-to-an-entire-row-or-column-using-r1c1-notation#comment110266909_62347205) as an answer, BigBen [did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62347668/11683) and marked it as community wiki.